# Loop Substituir todos caracters da string por caracter da lista python

Tags: python, string, lista, loop, replace

O que eu quero fazer é pegar uma string e pra cada caracter da string andar tipo 3 posições atras no alfabeto e substituir na string ou criar uma nova string
Ex string = 'abcd' andando 3 posições então String seria 'xyza'
Minha ideia  de código é  a seguinte:

```
a = 'ab cd mnopq stvux'
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
c = ''
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if(a[i] == b[i]):
            c =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos usar uma `collections.deque` pra podermos facilmente criar uma versão "rotacionada" do alfabeto. Em seguida, basta pegar a posição de cada letra no alfabeto e aplicar a posição equivalente no alfabeto rotacionado:

```
import collections

alfabeto = collections.deque('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
alfabeto_rotacionado = alfabeto.copy()
alfabeto_rotacionado.rotate(3)

print(alfabeto)  # deque(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' ...
print(alfabeto_rotacionado)  # deque(['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c' ...

mensagem = 'ab cd mnopq stvux'
mensagem_decifrada = ''
for letra in mensagem:
    if letra in alfabeto:
        # Se for um caractere no alfabeto...

        # Pegamos sua posição no alfabeto original
        posicao_alfabeto = alfabeto.index(letra)

        # Inserimos na mensagem decifrada o caractere equivalente no 
        # alfabeto rotacionado
        mensagem_decifrada += alfabeto_rotacionado[posicao_alfabeto]
    else:
        # Se não for um caractere no alfabeto, só incluímos o mesmo caractere
        # (espaço, pontuação, dígitos, etc.)
        mensagem_decifrada += letra

print(mensagem_decifrada)  # xy za jklmn pqsru
```